# Creating a step by step validation

Tags: java

I am trying to make a monitoring application for a FTP server using [FTP4J](http://www.sauronsoftware.it/projects/ftp4j/)(referred to as client in the code example).

It connects to a FTP, logs in, creates a file locally, uploads file, downloads file, validates the files are the same, cleans up files on ftp and locally and disconnects.

All this is already made but my question is how do I best log what has happened and break when an error is detected?

The simple solution I could think of was to make a Boolean that shows if previous steps where successful and only do next step if they where.

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
boolean noError = true;
// Connect to FTP
try {
    client.connect(hostname, port);
} catch (Exception e) {
    noError = false;
    sb.append("failed to connect<br>");
}

//Logging in to FTP
if(noError) {
    try {
        client.login(username, password);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        noError = false;
        sb.append("failed to login<br>");
    }
}
...
// Close connection
if(client.isConnected()) {
    try {
        client.disconnect(true);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        sb.append("failed to disconnect<br>");
    }
}
```

another solution I could think of was nested try/catch but that looked even worse, is there a better way of doing this?

Comment: How can it be `noError = false` inside the `catch` block?

Comment: @adarshr if you are in a catch block an error has occurred, so when asking if noError has occurred it should be false, is there something wrong with that logic?

Comment: I had got confused. This is why variables should not be named negatively. You could simply call it `success` and set to `false` or call it `error` and set it to `true` inside the `catch` block.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution is simple: don't catch the exception. As soon as an exception is thrown and is not caught, the whole process will stop. Or catch it but transform it into your own exception with the appropriate error message, and throw this exception.

Side note: you should use a `boolean` and not a `Boolean` to store a non-nullable boolean value.

Comment: How do I distinguish where the error occurred? or should I just say an error had occurred and add the exception to log?

Comment: Either you distinguish by catching and throwing another exception with the appropriate error message, or you store the last tried step in a variable, for example. When the exception is thrown, you inspect this variable to know what the last tried step was.

Answer (score 1):

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
Boolean noError = true;
// Connect to FTP
try {
    client.connect(hostname, port);
        client.login(username, password);

} catch (ConnectException ce) {
    sb.append("Couldn't connect: ");
    sb.append(ce.getMessage);
} catch (LoginException le) {
     sb.append("Couldn't login: ");
    sb.append(le.getMessage);

} finally {
if(client.isConnected()) {
    try {
        client.disconnect(true);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        sb.append("failed to disconnect<br>");
    }
}
```

Comment: I like this solution but [FTP4J](http://www.sauronsoftware.it/projects/ftp4j/manual.php#20) do not use thous exceptions.

Comment: True, it's a shame FTP4J doesn't distinguish between these two exceptions.